# how to add and subtract one year to the given date in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add one year to the given date in asp.net mvc4. Searched a lot in net for date time functions in mvc4 but no luck. please can anybody provide some links on the same.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: DateTime.AddYears() -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx   ???????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to your datetime object

```
dateTime.AddYears(1)
```